# web3 got duplicate events and make data in server different from blockchain

Tags: web3js, blockchain, events

I use web3j to listen ethereum smart contract events to synchronize data for the server, but sometimes I got duplicate events in one function.
Let's consider Birth evens in CryptoKitties smart contract, if there is only one kitty given birth and should only trigger one Birth event, but  on my web3 server which is listening to my local geth node, sometimes got 2 or 3 Birth events, with different kitty data (genes, owner , birthtime ...).
I know the issue is caused by the uncle blocks, but I really want a solution so that my server can synchronize exactly same data as the blockchain,  what should I do?
Thank  you  in advance!